# Is there any quick way to hibernate?

Tags: power-management

I am using Ubuntu 17.04, and have followed the hibernate guide at [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html), fortunately it worked.
I wonder if there is any way to hibernate except input command in terminal to hibernate? It would be better if someone knows how to show the hibernate choice in AllSettings-Power "when the lid is closed".

More detail: Sorry about the ambiguity, as a newbie to Ubuntu, I really don't know about hybrid-sleep.
After editing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to hibernate as super user as @Pilot6 suggested, I still can't see hibernate choice.
Changed both `HandlePowerKey=hibernate` and `HandleLidSwitch=hibernate` and reboot.

The latest update.(note that my reputation is less than 10, so I have to edit former links to make room for the more valuable one)
Tried several times to set different values said in [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html), finally I make it.

In my case, I changed every key to hibernate, and set LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no . Well, not elegant, but worked. Maybe someone can try to change just some keys to hibernate, but it's already too late for a Chinese, eleven o'clock at night.

Now my /etc/systemd/logind.conf is as below, other lines is still noted as default.

```
HandlePowerKey=hibernate  
HandleSuspendKey=hibernate  
HandleHibernateKey=hibernate  
HandleLidSwitch=hibernate  
HandleLidSwitchDocked=hibernate  
PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no  
SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no  
HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no  
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. There is `hybrid-sleep` that use both suspend and hibernate. You also can set `hibernate`, or hybrid-sleep` on lid close in a config file `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`. What do you really want?

Comment: it is also posible to set power button to hybernate instead of power off

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I suggest you to [edit] the question and make  it clear.

Comment: You won't see any "selection" in GUI, but the system will hibernate on lid close and on power button press. It some cases `HandleHibernateKey` is also needed depending on hardware.

Comment: @Pilot6 According to your clues , I find this https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html . After changed HandleHibernateKey , sometimes it works when lid close, but sometimes not. Still can't find a reason. Maybe as quoted below, some applications installed takes lock. When I figure it out, I'll come to share my solution. thx 
> This means that when systemd-logind is handling events by itself (no low level inhibitor locks are taken by another application), the lid switch does not respect suspend blockers by default, but the power and sleep keys do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this kind of options in `/etc/sytemd/logind.conf` file.

If you want to hibernate the laptop on lid close, uncomment the

```
#HandleLidSwitch=
```

line to look this way:

```
HandleLidSwitch=hibernate
```

You can also use `hybrid-sleep` instead of `hibernate` to use both options. The laptop will wake up fast, but if battery is drained, it won't lose data.

Also you can set the power button behavior using

```
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
```

line.

You will need to reboot to apply the settings.

Comment: thanks and sorry for the ambiguity. I have edit my question, hoping for your further help.